# Can I edit some type of R Studio config file instead of changing all options through the GUI?

Tags: r, rstudio

[According to this forum post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000932128-RStudio-Config-Files), that's now several years old, there's no easy way to edit R Studio's config files to alter R Studio's options. It seems the only option is to use the GUI `Tools > Global Options`.

Is there any novel solution to mass apply custom settings to an R Studio instance without having to point-and-click dozens of GUI options?

Comment: I know this isn't a great solution but have you tried copying the files from this folder into a new device and seeing if it transports the config (For windows machines)? %localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop

Comment: Have you tried asking on the [R Studio community](https://community.rstudio.com)?

Answer (score 0):

There sure is.  You can adjust your Rprofile which is a SITE File.  In my R instance, it's in the etc folder.  Open this folder with a regular text editor or in R studio and add lines of code to this file that you want implemented every time you start an R session.

For example, used the `options` function to set my CRAN repo and used the `.libPaths` function to make my libraries install in a folder I wanted them to install in.

Comment: This only applies to R options, not to RStudio configuration preferences, right? Tools...Global options has things like choosing your R version and notifications for updates to RStudio. Are you saying those options can be set with `options()`?

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm not sure . . . I would think that anything you could write in the terminal could be put there.